# WPF is it possible to fill DataGrid with the ObjectDataProvider?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I ask this question because I can't get it to work.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="vmObjDataProv" ObjectType="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The thing is that when I use the following xaml it works (the ListBox is filled):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmObjDataProv}, Path=TestList}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

But when I do the following it doesn't work anymore:

```
<Grid>
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource vmObjDataProv}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" Background="White">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--EDITORS-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Editor" IsReadOnly="True" Width="auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Why don't you simply declare the view model as resource, i.e. `<vm:SomeViewModel x:Key="vm"/>` and bind to it like `DataContext="{StaticResource vm}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"`? That said, a UserControl should never have its "own" view model. The DataContext value should instead be inherited from its parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that the binding mechanism, as in this case:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmObjDataProv}, Path=TestList}" />
```

is designed to replace `ObjectDataProvider` with actual provided data (an instance of `SomeViewModel` in your case). However, when you have a simple resource reference:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource vmObjDataProv}" />
```

the replacement does not happen, thus the actual `DataContext` is the `ObjectDataProvider` itself, and not an instance of `SomeViewModel`. The correct setup would be this:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmObjDataProv}}" />
```